How can we prevent wallet to not hold more than 1% token if market cap is under 1B
I am building a token and i want to wallets to not buy much token. How can we prevent wallet to not hold more than 1%  token if market cap is under 1B.
How can i achieve this , Please keep in mind that users can buy from any exchange like raydium , jupiter .

You can use transfer hooks for this. The below transfer hook in anchor ensures that no address ever has more than 1000 tokens for example. The key parts to this are the MAX_AMOUNT constant and the transfer_hook function. This example is based on the example from the docs which also has more info on how to use these. Adapting this to include dynamic max balances depending on the current market cap is left as an exercise to the reader ;).
use anchor_lang::{
    prelude::*,
    system_program::{create_account, CreateAccount},
};
use anchor_spl::{
    associated_token::AssociatedToken,
    token_interface::{Mint, TokenAccount, TokenInterface},
};
use spl_tlv_account_resolution::state::ExtraAccountMetaList;
use spl_transfer_hook_interface::instruction::{ExecuteInstruction, TransferHookInstruction};

pub const MAX_AMOUNT: u64 = 1000;

#[error_code]
pub enum TransferError {
    TooMuchBalance,
}

declare_id!("4A8scXS2rchG7Zi3WXSUTiXFEPNRafekxqg2skv2jqcC");

#[program]
pub mod transfer_hook {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize_extra_account_meta_list(
        ctx: Context<InitializeExtraAccountMetaList>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        // The `addExtraAccountsToInstruction` JS helper function resolving incorrectly
        let account_metas = vec![];

        // calculate account size
        let account_size = ExtraAccountMetaList::size_of(account_metas.len())? as u64;
        // calculate minimum required lamports
        let lamports = Rent::get()?.minimum_balance(account_size as usize);

        let mint = ctx.accounts.mint.key();
        let signer_seeds: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[&[
            b"extra-account-metas",
            &mint.as_ref(),
            &[ctx.bumps.extra_account_meta_list],
        ]];

        // create ExtraAccountMetaList account
        create_account(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                CreateAccount {
                    from: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.extra_account_meta_list.to_account_info(),
                },
            ).with_signer(signer_seeds),
            lamports,
            account_size,
            ctx.program_id,
        )?;

        // initialize ExtraAccountMetaList account with extra accounts
        ExtraAccountMetaList::init::<ExecuteInstruction>(
            &mut ctx.accounts.extra_account_meta_list.try_borrow_mut_data()?,
            &account_metas,
        )?;

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn transfer_hook(ctx: Context<TransferHook>, _amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        require!(
            ctx.accounts.destination_token.amount < MAX_AMOUNT,
            TransferError::TooMuchBalance
        );

        Ok(())
    }

    // fallback instruction handler as workaround to anchor instruction discriminator check
    pub fn fallback<'info>(
        program_id: &Pubkey,
        accounts: &'info [AccountInfo<'info>],
        data: &[u8],
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let instruction = TransferHookInstruction::unpack(data)?;

        // match instruction discriminator to transfer hook interface execute instruction
        // token2022 program CPIs this instruction on token transfer
        match instruction {
            TransferHookInstruction::Execute { amount } => {
                let amount_bytes = amount.to_le_bytes();

                // invoke custom transfer hook instruction on our program
                __private::__global::transfer_hook(program_id, accounts, &amount_bytes)
            }
            _ => return Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData.into()),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeExtraAccountMetaList<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    payer: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK: ExtraAccountMetaList Account, must use these seeds
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"extra-account-metas", mint.key().as_ref()], 
        bump
    )]
    pub extra_account_meta_list: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    pub token_program: Interface<'info, TokenInterface>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

// Order of accounts matters for this struct.
// The first 4 accounts are the accounts required for token transfer (source, mint, destination, owner)
// Remaining accounts are the extra accounts required from the ExtraAccountMetaList account
// These accounts are provided via CPI to this program from the token2022 program
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransferHook<'info> {
    #[account(
        token::mint = mint, 
        token::authority = owner,
    )]
    pub source_token: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        token::mint = mint,
    )]
    pub destination_token: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
    /// CHECK: source token account owner, can be SystemAccount or PDA owned by another program
    pub owner: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: ExtraAccountMetaList Account,
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"extra-account-metas", mint.key().as_ref()], 
        bump
    )]
    pub extra_account_meta_list: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}

Here's a Typescript test function that shows how to use it:
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { TransferHook } from "../target/types/transfer_hook";
import {
  PublicKey,
  SystemProgram,
  Transaction,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
  Keypair,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  ExtensionType,
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
  getMintLen,
  createInitializeMintInstruction,
  createInitializeTransferHookInstruction,
  ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction,
  createMintToInstruction,
  createTransferCheckedInstruction,
  getAssociatedTokenAddressSync,
  createTransferCheckedWithTransferHookInstruction,
} from "@solana/spl-token";

describe("transfer-hook", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);

  const program = anchor.workspace.TransferHook as Program<TransferHook>;
  const wallet = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;
  const connection = provider.connection;

  // Generate keypair to use as address for the transfer-hook enabled mint
  const mint = new Keypair();
  const decimals = 9;

  // Sender token account address
  const sourceTokenAccount = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
    mint.publicKey,
    wallet.publicKey,
    false,
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
    ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  // Recipient token account address
  const recipient = Keypair.generate();
  const destinationTokenAccount = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
    mint.publicKey,
    recipient.publicKey,
    false,
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
    ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  // ExtraAccountMetaList address
  // Store extra accounts required by the custom transfer hook instruction
  const [extraAccountMetaListPDA] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("extra-account-metas"), mint.publicKey.toBuffer()],
    program.programId
  );

  it("Create Mint Account with Transfer Hook Extension", async () => {
    const extensions = [ExtensionType.TransferHook];
    const mintLen = getMintLen(extensions);
    const lamports =
      await provider.connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(mintLen);

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: mint.publicKey,
        space: mintLen,
        lamports: lamports,
        programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
      }),
      createInitializeTransferHookInstruction(
        mint.publicKey,
        wallet.publicKey,
        program.programId, // Transfer Hook Program ID
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
      ),
      createInitializeMintInstruction(
        mint.publicKey,
        decimals,
        wallet.publicKey,
        null,
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
      )
    );

    const txSig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      provider.connection,
      transaction,
      [wallet.payer, mint]
    );
    console.log(`Transaction Signature: ${txSig}`);
  });

  // Create the two token accounts for the transfer-hook enabled mint
  // Fund the sender token account with 100 tokens
  it("Create Token Accounts and Mint Tokens", async () => {
    // 100 tokens
    const amount = 100 * 10 ** decimals;

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        wallet.publicKey,
        sourceTokenAccount,
        wallet.publicKey,
        mint.publicKey,
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
      ),
      createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        wallet.publicKey,
        destinationTokenAccount,
        recipient.publicKey,
        mint.publicKey,
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
      ),
      createMintToInstruction(
        mint.publicKey,
        sourceTokenAccount,
        wallet.publicKey,
        amount,
        [],
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
      )
    );

    const txSig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      transaction,
      [wallet.payer],
      { skipPreflight: true }
    );

    console.log(`Transaction Signature: ${txSig}`);
  });

  // Account to store extra accounts required by the transfer hook instruction
  it("Create ExtraAccountMetaList Account", async () => {
    const initializeExtraAccountMetaListInstruction = await program.methods
      .initializeExtraAccountMetaList()
      .accounts({
        mint: mint.publicKey,
        extraAccountMetaList: extraAccountMetaListPDA,
      })
      .instruction();

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      initializeExtraAccountMetaListInstruction
    );

    const txSig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      provider.connection,
      transaction,
      [wallet.payer],
      { skipPreflight: true, commitment: "confirmed" }
    );
    console.log("Transaction Signature:", txSig);
  });

  it("Transfer Hook with Extra Account Meta", async () => {
    const amount = 100;
    const bigIntAmount = BigInt(amount);

    // Standard token transfer instruction
    const transferInstruction = await createTransferCheckedWithTransferHookInstruction(
      connection,
      sourceTokenAccount,
      mint.publicKey,
      destinationTokenAccount,
      wallet.publicKey,
      bigIntAmount,
      decimals,
      [],
      "confirmed",
      TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      transferInstruction
    );

    const txSig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      transaction,
      [wallet.payer],
      { skipPreflight: true }
    );
    console.log("Transfer Signature:", txSig);
  });
});


yes I tried and when i try to create-extra-metas using ProgramId of transfer and Mint , compiler is not initializing extra-metas account itself.

Also raydium is not supporting transfer hook extension right now.

I've extended my answer to include a typescript example of how to call it.

Unfortunately there's no other way to add custom functionality to tokens if not by token extensions, so if Raydium doesn't support it and you need Raydium, your ask is currently impossible. I know Raydium is working on this though since they already support some extensions, so with a bit of luck transfer hooks should be supported soon too: https://docs.raydium.io/raydium/updates/token-2022-support

Ok instead of typescript client how we can achive it using cli , I tried with cli but create-extra-metas are creating mess .

I'm not sure, but it's outside the scope of this question. If you're interested in how to create a token22 token using the CLI, I suggest accepting this answer and opening a new question asking about this & specifying the exact error message you're getting.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
